# Cloudflare CacheEverything : How to bypass Wordpress' Admin Bar for logged-in users?

Tags: wordpress, static, cloudflare

I have setup cloudflare to cache everything for my wordpress site. My page rules are like the following:

- mydomain.tld/wp-admin
  Cache Level - Bypass
- mydomain.tld/*?*loggedin=true
  Cache Level - Bypass
- mydomain.tld/*
  Cache Level - Cache Everything

To avoid caching admin-bar, i only enable admin-bar-rendering in wordpress when url has parameter "loggedin=true".

It's working great but I wonder if there is a way to make it work without having the extra "loggedin=true" parameter?

This [post](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/cache-everything-with-wordpress/556) is closest to my situation. Currently the solutions proposed from the discussion are either:

- using on-site cache plugin like Comet Cache or
- pay 200/month for business plan

Comment: If you were using CloudFlare Wordpress APO it would be doing that for you automatically https://www.cloudflare.com/automatic-platform-optimization/wordpress/

Comment: For me, even with APO active, the bar continues to be cached.